# Microsoft Entra ID Free instead of Auth0

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-entra-id, microsoft-entra-internet-access

We are trying to use Microsoft Entra ID instead of Auth0 as we're building APIs and Applications in Azure so it seems sensible to keep with the same platform for speed and integration.

The MS docs are confusing, particularly as they have changed the name from Azure Active Directory to Entra ID.

Is someone able to confirm if Entra ID:

1. Can be set up with your own login page instead of using the MS one?
2. Can accept API requests to Register / Send Password Reset Email / Change Password
3. Can be used to authenticate to subdomains using OAuth 2.0

We don't need Google/Facebook/Apple 3rd party logins or other more advanced features.

This is an email/password login system for one main site with a couple of subdomain sites.

We need to build the login page with company branding and not the MS branded pages, even though I can see they can be somewhat customised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that we need [Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview) which is soon going to be renamed as [Azure Entra External ID](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-entra-azure-ad-blog/microsoft-entra-external-id-public-preview-developer-centric/ba-p/3823766) but hasn't been released yet.

I think we then need to use the Graph API to manage register/edit/delete/password-reset methods for users